# animateLayoutChanges to true is causing layout to move up and down in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am dragging elements from one HorizontalScrollView to another HorizontalScrollView.

When dropped I am removing the view from bottom HorizontalScrollView and adding it to the top HorizontalScrollView. I am animating the changes by setting the xml `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

The changes are being animated, that is not the problem. The problem is that the whenever those animations are triggered the layout moves up and down. When I drag an item it goes up and on another drag it goes down. And it repeats for all consequent drags.

Here is a video showing the problem : https://sendvid.com/uqnnwc4v

My XMl is this :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp">
        <include layout="@layout/content_package_description_horizontal_view"/>
       ........
    </RelativeLayout>
..........
..........
..........
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false">
            <!-- Package list -->
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
            <include layout="@layout/service_single_hero"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And I am adding to the upper HorizontalScrollView like this

```
// Adding to Horizontal view
    FrameLayout thisHorizontalBigItem = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.package_description_horizontal_item_big, null, false);
    TextView thisHorizontalBigTextView = (TextView) thisHorizontalBigItem.findViewById(
            R.id.selected_service_item_big_text_view);
    thisHorizontalBigTextView.setText("ID : " + itemID);

    horizontalItemsContainer.addView(thisHorizontalBigItem, 0);
```

Removing from the bottom HorizontalScrollView like this:

```
// Remove the selected service from bottom list
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < servicesItemsContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View thisServiceItem = servicesItemsContainer.getChildAt(i);
            JSONObject thisItemJSON = new JSONObject(thisServiceItem.getTag().toString());
            if (thisItemJSON.getInt("id") == itemID) {
                servicesItemsContainer.removeView(thisServiceItem);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please tell me what's wrong here ?